# Have you seen or did you see

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

In US, when people work together, they may look for a colleague or any person to tell something or for any other reason, asking other collegues/people such a question:

> Have you seen Michael?

or

> Did you see Michael?

Which is considered right if the question refers to an activity (in our case "see") during a day and not the past in general?

Comment: If you'd like to delete your own question, please use the *delete* button instead of vandalizing it.

Answer (score 1):

They have similar meanings. "Have you seen Michael" is more generally useful.

> "I was just in the break room eating lunch"
>
> "Did you see Michael (in the break room)?"

vs.

> "Have you seen Michael (anywhere, anytime, within reason)?"

"Yes, he's in the break room", "He was in the sales meeting this morning", "I saw him yesterday, I don't know if he's in today", "I haven't seen him all week".